# Why getting error: class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime-error, nsdictionary

As suggested in Xcode autocomplete suggestion using below code in objective c produced runtime error,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%d", i);

    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic setValue:@"Alex" forKey:@"name"];
    [dic setValue:@"45" forKey:@"Age"];
}
```

> 2020-03-29 21:55:34.588607+0600 Test[5299:15492347] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[<__NSDictionary0 0x7fff806228e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

**What am I missing?**

#### Update

As [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) commented `NSDictionary` is not mutable, then,

1. Why `setValue` method is available for NSDictionary in Autocomplete suggestion on Xcode?
2. Why can't methods that modifies non mutable collections be detected on compile time rather runtime?

Comment: “What am I missing?” Everything. An NSDictionary is not mutable. You cannot set anything in it. Moreover, `setValue` is the wrong mechanism. Basically, nothing whatever about that code is right.

Comment: @matt why setValue method is there if we cannot use it?

Comment: It is KVC. You don’t need KVC here. Just call `setObject`. Of course, you cannot, because this is not a mutable dictionary. But that’s the point.

Comment: "NSDictionary is not mutable, then why setValue method is available for NSDictionary" Because it is a category on NSObject. All classes inherit it. But that doesn't mean you can _use_ it to try to work around the fact that a class is not mutable. All classes inherit `copy` but not all classes conform to NSCopying. And so on.

Comment: I understand. Why Apple is not removing those unusable methods from non mutable collections? any idea? @matt

Comment: It _did_ remove it. That is what the exception tells you.

Comment: @matt I mean from autocomplete suggestion on Xcode?

Comment: And why can't they detect in compile time? @matt

Comment: Because it is an NSObject method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue by changing `setValue` to `setObject`,

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setObject:@"Alex" forKey:@"name"];
[dic setObject:@"45" forKey:@"Age"];
```